# The number of planes that hold the edges of a pyramid

Tags: geometry

The number of planes which hold the edges of the pentagonal pyramid is .....

My attempt:

There is one plane for the base
And there are $5$ planes for the faces and there is a plane for each non-adjacent pair of edges
Which are $5$ pairs so the number of planes is $1 +5 + 5$ = $11$

Is this correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the five triangular faces is in a plane.  Those five planes hold all the edges.  You can do better by taking the base and three of the triangles that do not share an edge.  That gets you down to four planes.

Comment: But Hussien Mohamed is including the the planes that pass through the pyramid that contain opposite edges.

Comment: @user247327:  I read the question to ask for the minimum number of planes that will contain all the edges.  That is how I understand hold.  There are pairs of edges that are not in any plane, so I don't think one should try to count the number of planes determined by the pairs of edges.